# Find all entries while they have different numbers in notepad++ using regex

Tags: regex

I have some files that may contain these lines:

```
npc[0].type=XY
npc[1].type=XY
npc[2].type=XY
```

and so on.

The number in the brackets [] can be something from 0 to 9.

I need to find all cases in the files where such a line exists.

I tried `npc[\d{1}].type=`  so far, but then it finds 0 results.

I expect to find all cases of these lines, regardless of the number within the brackets

Answer (score 1):

```
^npc\[\d{1}\].+$
```

Explained:

`^` = Start of String

`npc\[` = The text "npc["

`\d{1}` = Exactly one digit

`\]` = The text "]"

`.+` = Any character except newline with at least 1 or more occurrences

`$` = End of String

You may want to add global & case-insensitive flags (`gi`).

Comment: and how can I add the ".type"?

Comment: @WombiWombyte Just add the .type and escape the dot: `^npc\[\d{1}\]\.type.+$`

Answer (score 0):

Escape the opening square bracket `\[` and escape the dot to match it literally `\.` and omit `{1}` as that is the default:

```
npc\[\d]\.type=
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/155TlN/1)

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has great documentation on regular expression pattern syntax.
*[Wikipedia – Regular expression – Syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Syntax)*.

Your error is that the square-bracket characters are meta-characters—they're being interpreted as syntax.

Precede a meta-character with a *reverse-solidus* character, \, to *"un-escape"* it as syntax.

```
npc\[\d{1}\].type=
```

Additionally, the quantifier of 1 would be redundant—and untimately, is optional if *1*.